# How to find and replace block of codes in bash on multiple files on multiple folder

Tags: bash, server

Hi have this dilemma that where i have multiple blocks of code in multiple files and in multiple folder now i wanted to make change in one go.

Heres the code in bash

```
    #! /bin/bash

findcode="<form name="activateform" id="activateform" method="post" action="<?php echo network_site_url('wp-activate.php'); ?>">
            <p>
                <label for="key"><?php _e('Activation Key:') ?></label>
                <br /><input type="text" name="key" id="key" value="" size="50" />
            </p>
            <p class="submit">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="Submit" class="submit" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Activate') ?>" />
            </p>
        </form>"
replacecode="<?php if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit } ?>"
for grep -lr $findcode * do
    sed -i 's/$findcode/replacecode/g' folders and subfolders
done
```

Basically the idea is

```
blocCodeToBeReplace = <?php block of code here ?>

blockCodeToReplace = <?php block of code here to replace including code ?>
```

find $blocCodeToBeReplace on all .php files on each folder and subfolder then replace $blockCodeToReplace.

Comment: Read about find(1) and sed(1); it's not very easy, but in a single line you can do what you want.

Comment: Yes single line of code is easy but this is multiple line of code including non alpahbet character i did not put the code here as it is sensitive info